# Debug my reimplementation of strtok and split

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to be writing code that takes a string of comma separated values without spaces (ex. `my,name,is,jack`). First we had to write a function

```
string nextstring(string str, int start_index)
```

that returns a single "value" from your initial string depending on the start index. The second part of the problem was to write a function

```
int split(string str, string a[], int max_size)
```

that will identify all the values in the initial string and put them in a string array and then return the total number of values stored in the array; i.e. if you had initially input `my,name,is` it would return 3.

My function never returns the correct value and whatever it returns changes depending on what the length of the words are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string nextstring(string str, int start_index);
int split(string str, string a[], int max_size);

int main()
{
    string str;
    int cnt;

    string a[100];

    cout<< "what is your string" << endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    cnt= split(str, a, 100);
    cout << "There are " << cnt << " values in this string" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}

string nextstring(string str, int start_index)
{
    string ans;

    if(str[start_index] == ',' || str[start_index] == '\0')
    {
        ans=" ";
    }
    else{
        ans=str[start_index]+nextstring(str, start_index+1);
    }

    return ans;

}

int split(string str, string a[], int max_size)
{
    int j=0;
    int ans=0;
    double k=0;
    while(j<max_size)
    {
        a[j]= nextstring(str,k);
        string check=a[j];

        if(isalpha(check[0])!= 0)
        {
          ans++;
        }
        k=k+a[j].length();
        j++;
     }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Recommendation: instead of returning `ans=" ";`, return `ans="";` An empty string is more easily recognizable as an empty string than a string with a space in it.

Comment: Another recommendation: when posting questions to SO remove all of the user input and force the program to run with a set of canned inputs that will trigger the bad behaviour. This allows us to see exactly what you are seeing rather than guessing at your test inputs.

Comment: Think on why `k` is a `double`. Are you expecting half a string? Also think on why `k` is named `k`. `k` tells the reader absolutely nothing about the purpose of `k` and makes debugging more difficult for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that `while(j<max_size){...}` leads to `j` being incremented up to `max_size`. The line `a[j]= nextstring(str,k);` is at some points reading values that are outside your string which is really bad!

Replacing `while(j<max_size){...}` by `while(j<max_size && k<str.length()){...}` seems to be enough to make your code work!

---

Apart from that:

1. `k` has no reason to be a double! It should be an `int` (or something similar).
2. Since you are already using [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), you should also learn to use [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). `split` is better written as:

   ```
   int split(string str, vector<string> &a, int max_size)
   {
       int ans=0;
       int k=0;
       while(k<str.length())
       {
           string next = nextstring(str,k);

           if(isalpha(next[0])!= 0)
           {
               ans++;
               a.append(next);
           }
           k += next.length();
        }
        return ans;
   }
   ```

Comment: I would recommend `k` be a `size_t` because it is big enough to index even the most insanely large string and there is no point to allowing the possibility of a negative index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your approach is to identify the end of the string, as there is no null terminator in a c++ string.  Consider to update `nextstring()` to look for the end of string in a different manner:

```
string nextstring(string str, int start_index) 
{
    ...
    if(start_index == str.size() || str[start_index] == ',' ) //<===
    {
        ans=" ";
    }
    ...
}
```

[**online demo**](http://ideone.com/AVt6oJ)

**Additional recommendation**

Note that it is not very nice to return a blank string when in reality it should be empty to reflect its real value (e.g. ",,").  You have no choice because otherwise you would have no mean in the calling function, to determine that the end of string was reached.  But the consequence is thar all your strings have a trailing blank.

When you call recursively the function adding char to build the return string, you risk to have a considerable overhead.  You could consider avoiding this, by replacing the else part:

```
    ans=str.substr(start_index, str.find(',', start_index+1)-start_index);
```

However, as you have no trailing blank anymore, you need to adapt `split()` so to adapt its way to count the total number of chars parsed:

```
    k=k+a[j].length()+1;  // +1 because there's no longer a trailing blank.
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/ZVAeb4)